# Linq Join error

Tags: c#, linq

I'm receiving the following error on the below linq query (line 2) and I don't understand how to correct it.

> The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. 
>   Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

All 2 variables in the equals expression are (string) so I'm not sure why this error would result. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
var studentlist = from t1 in  Extern
                  join t2 in EMPstatus //m receiving the error here 
                  on new { t1.id} equals new { id= t2.id }
                  join t3 in StatusofEmp
                  on new { t2.Sta_ID } equals new {Sta_ID = t3.Sta_ID }
                  where t3.Status = "INAKTIV" 
                  select new { t1.Name };
```

Comment: Can we get snippets of the type class definitions?

Comment: While it looks like it *should* work, it would be simpler as `on t1.id equals t2.id` and later `on t2.Sta_ID equals t3.Sta_ID`.

Comment: (Likewise you can just `select t1.Name` - you don't need to use anonymous types everywhere.) Can you get just *one* join to work? Oh, and I notice your `where` clause is invalid at the moment - you want `where t3.Status == "INAKTIV"` - note the `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: What is the type of each of the following expressions: `t1.id`, `t2.id`, `t2.Sta_ID`, `Sta_ID`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create new anonymous objects when using `join`.

Try something like this instead:

```
var studentlist = 
    from t1 in  Extern
    join t2 in EMPstatus
    on t1.id equals t2.id
    join t3 in StatusofEmp
    on t2.Sta_ID equals t3.Sta_ID
    where t3.Status = "INAKTIV" 
    select new { t1.Name };
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description i guess one of your id column may be nullable and another one is not nullable allowed.Check which one is nullable ,suppose t1  id is nullable and t2 id is not nullable then in join condition set bellow syntax `id=(t1.id??0) equals t2.id`

Hope above syntax help to solve your issue.

```
var studentlist = from t1 in  Extern
                  join t2 in EMPstatus //m receiving the error here 
                  on  id=(t1.id??0) equals  id= t2.id 
                  join t3 in StatusofEmp
                  on new { t2.Sta_ID } equals new {Sta_ID = t3.Sta_ID }
                  where t3.Status = "INAKTIV" 
                  select new { t1.Name };
```

Comment: It could be that one is nullable, or one could be a double while another is an int, or one could be the string representation of a number while another is actually a number, or any number of other options.  The OP really needs to state the relevant types for an answer to be given.  Also, this code won't compile with the two `id=` bits added.  Just remove them.